# Swift iOS check if a file has been downloaded from json

Tags: ios, json, swift, file, save

I have an app that displays and plays a list of podcasts that is fetched from a json file, I would like to add a download feature but to do this I would like to only show a download icon if the podcast has not been downloaded already, is there a way that I can save something like the id element as well as the podcast title so I could then check to see if its been downloaded and saved on the phone already? Or is there an easier way? Obviously I would like to do this before the list is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) for that.
Here's an example on how to read an array from UserDefaults

```
// Retrieves an array of strings from disk
func getDowloadedPodcasts() -> [String] {
    UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "downloadedPodcasts") as? [String] ?? []
}
```

And here's an example on how to append a new value to an array on UserDefaults

```
func addDownloadedPodcast(podcastId: String) {
    let downloadedPodcasts = getDowloadedPodcasts()
    downloadedPodcasts.append(podcastId)
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(podcastId, forKey: "downloadedPodcasts")
}
```

Note that this functions alone won't solve your problem nor are the best solution of your problem, they are here jsut to show how easy it can be to work with UserDefaults and to read/write from non-volatile memory